# Inject script tag after generated bundle in ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm building a ReactJS application and there is a need to add `<script>` tag. I can do it right in the index.html, but this doesn't solve my problem because:

1. All scripts must be injected right before closing `</body>`.
2. My extra `<script>` tag must be added after generated bundle.

What solution may be applied to achieve this?

Here part of my Webpack configuration:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
      app: [
          './src/main.jsx',
      ],
  },
  output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      filename: '[name].[hash].js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].[hash].js',
      publicPath: '/',
  },

  plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          title: 'App name',
          description: 'App description',
          template: './public/index.html',
          inject: true,
      }),
  ],
}
```

And index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fi">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="app"></div>
      <!-- generated bundle will be injected here -->
      <!-- I need my extra script tags injected here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Additional scripts can't be loaded asynchronously.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer given by @James Morrison works well, I would use this approach next time, but it doesn't solve my current problem. I ended up with injecting generated bundle and CSS manually within `body`:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js.length; i++) {%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js[i] %>"></script>
<% } %>
```

and `head` respectively:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css.length; i++) {%>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[i] %>">
<% } %>
```

Also `inject` option in webpack configuration is set to `false`:

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'App name',
      description: 'App description',
      template: './public/index.html',
      inject: false,
  }),
],
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend adding this via javascript within a component as React has done a pretty good job of stopping scripts from executing properly otherwise. For example in your componentDidMount function on app.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = {url_to_your_script};
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```